# gcloud failed to load: libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found

Tags: python-2.7, openssl

While trying to use gcloud I'm seeing this error:

```
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: /tmp/_MEIKmE9I5/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
    gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
    import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main                              
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import cli
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import backend
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import parser_extensions
    from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import update_manager
    from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import installers    
    import ssl                                 
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate

This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.

Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 executable:
    /usr/bin/python2                                         

If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 executable.

If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:                                                                                                                 
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
```

Here's some system information:

```
➜  uname -a
Linux stian-Lenovo-Y520-15IKBN 4.13.0-45-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 30 11:18:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
➜  /usr/bin/python2 -V
Python 2.7.12
➜  python -V    
Python 2.7.12
➜  python -c 'import _ssl; print _ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
➜  openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

And I do have a file `libssl.so.1.0.0`:

```
➜  ll /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 419K juni  20 14:32 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
```

I've installed these packages after suggestions from various stackoverflow threads: `libssl1.0.0 libssl1.0.0:i386 openssl libssl-dev libudev-dev`. But I'm still seeing the same error. I've also tried to remove gcloud completely and reinstall it without avail.

Any tips to help figure this out would be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: at the 1rst line : "/tmp/_MEIKmE9I5/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found"; how can it found OpenSSL1.0.2 with a lib1.0.0?

Comment: did you check if`/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` exist ?

Comment: Thank you for replying! I just checked and `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so` does exist. `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 101K des.   4  2017 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: Hey @L42 were you able to uncover what is causing this error? I have exactly the same error on CircleCI using google/cloud-sdk images

Comment: @GrzegorzKapkowski Sorry, I don't recall. I have not seen the same error in my most recent installations of gcloud.

Comment: I just had this problem and solved it by deleting `~/.docker/config.json` which apparently I had screwed up.

Answer (score 6):

I was actually running into this on [Google Cloud Shell](https://ssh.cloud.google.com/cloudshell/editor) but with OpenSSL 1.1. The error was something like *gcloud failed to load libssl.so.1.1* and it was attempting to load from `/tmp/` which seemed bizarre to me. I finally came across an answer (https://superuser.com/a/1411019/299738) that helped:

```bsh
rm ~/.docker/config.json
```

I think I screwed things up when I was creating a virtualenv for an old version of Python (2.7).

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same, my solution was to read the error message... it was suggesting to check the python path which was pointing to:

```
/snap/microk8s/1910/usr/bin/python3
```

(not sure why)

so I did the suggested fix:

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

and then it works.